# flutter: onTap Button listenable not work on position in stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I Trying to create a custom dialog. In dialog Close button is above of container:

[image]

Now I am trying to close dialog when user Tapped on this close icon:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: true,
                  child: Positioned(
                    top: -15,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("Clicked");
                        },
                        child: CircleWidget()),
                  ),
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
```

But onTap not triggered ! I think it's lay down under some widget!!!

If GestureDetector be parent of `Positioned` on widget shape is messed.like this:

[image]

Although **onTap** not work like above .What is your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess before, a widget covered **GestureDetector** so I changed the position of This code :

```
Visibility(
  visible: widget.showCloseButton(),
  child: Positioned(
    top: -15,
    left: 0,
```

with :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

Now GestureDetector works like a charm :-)

complete code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(.....

                Visibility(
                  visible: true,
                  child: Positioned(
                    top: -15,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("Clicked");
                        },
                        child: CircleWidget()),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

****My Previous Answer was deleted for not giving an example, This is a modification

The solution did not work for my case. The button I wanted was positioned outside the bounds of the stack...Positioned(top: -30, ...)

However, The package https://pub.dev/packages/defer_pointer solved my case.

1. Wrap a `DeferredPointerHandler` somewhere above the buttons that you wish to hit-test.
2. Wrap `DeferPointer` around the buttons themselves.

```
return DeferredPointerHandler(
   child: SizedBox(
       width: 100,
       height: 100,
       child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
         // Hang button off the bottom of the content
         Positioned(
           bottom: -30,
           child: DeferPointer(child: _SomeBtn(false)),
         ),
         // Content
         Positioned.fill(
           child: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, boxShadow: [
               BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1), blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 4),
             ]),
           ),
         ),
       ]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

**try InkWell instend of GestureDetector**

```
child: InkWell(onTap: () {
       print("Clicked");
},
child: CircleWidget()),
```

Comment: I tried but not worked like GestureDetector @milanpithadia